# Reading large database table into Dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask-dataframe

I have a 7GB postgresql table which I want to read into python and do some analysis. I cannot use Pandas for it because it is larger than the memory on my local machine. I therefore wanted to try reading the table into Dask Dataframe first, perform some aggregation and switch back to Pandas for subsequent analysis. I used the below lines of code for that.

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('table_xyz', uri = "postgresql+psycopg2://user:pwd@remotehost/dbname", index_col = 'column_xyz', schema = 'private')
```

The index_col i.e. 'column_xyz' is indexed in database. This works but when I perform an action for example an aggregation, it takes ages (like an hour) to return the result.

```
avg = df.groupby("col1").col2.mean().compute()
```

I understand that Dask is not as fast as Pandas more so when I am working on a single machine and not a cluster. I am wondering whether I am using Dask the right way? If not what is a faster alternative to perform analysis on large tables that do not fit in memory using Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your data fits into the RAM of your machine then you're better off using Pandas. Dask will not outperform Pandas in some cases.
Alternatively you can play around with the chunksize and see if things improve. The best way to figure this out is to look at dask diagnostics tool dashboard and figure out what is taking dask so long. That will help you make a much more informed decision.

Comment: Could you refer to any link where Dask.dataframe chunksize is explained in detailed. I could not find any resource going in depth about chunksize selection.

Comment: I have just realized that the chunksize is not used with read_sql_table because you need to partition using an index column. Also you are calculating the avg using the pandas dataframe so you're not leveraging dask for that. Try calculating the average using dask dataframe(very similar commands to pandas) and check the diagnostics dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I set 'bytes_per_chunk' parameter to 30MB along with the mandatory 'index_col' parameter and that has helped. Now the action is completed in 9 minutes which is acceptable.